# New shower valve not working - tried multiple cartridges!

Tags: shower, valve, cartridge

I recently installed a [Moen posi-temp valve](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081W6QHFD) for a shower (shower only, no tub) renovation.

I have tried 4 different cartridges and they all don't work properly.

- First one - had terrible pressure and temperature didn't change
- Second one - same thing
- Third one (off brand moen cartridge) - the temperature changed but the pressure would only be hard for about 10 seconds when turned all the way to hot.
- Fourth one - better pressure, but not full pressure, and the temperature only gets to warm and then I can't turn it back to cold. It stays same temperture no matter how I turn it.

Without the cartridge, I tested the hot and cold water lines and both pour out of the opening. The pressure and temperature in the rest of the house faucets and upstairs shower works as it should.

**I'm starting to wonder if I need a different shower valve.**

FYI. The shower previously had a valve that I pulled the handle out to turn on.

Any suggestions would be amazing.

Comment: Have you contacted Moen support? 1-800-289-6636

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes. I've talked to them twice. But wanted to see if anyone had opinions on this before I speak to them again.